# Why I getting only 1 post?

Tags: posts, wp-query

I'm using the following basic code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php

$args = array(
'status'        => 'publish',
'post_type'     => 'radio',
'orderby'       => 'date',
'order'         => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and run it (under taxonomy.php) and I gets only one post - I have lot of 'radio' poststypes.
What it worng here? Thanks!

Comment: Do "radio" post types have titles? Why not try debugging inside your loop a little, or debugging your query. Try, after $query is defined, typing "var_dump($query);" and see what comes up.

Comment: yes the all 'radio' posts has a title.

Comment: And how and what can I debug here? It's saw me only the 1st post :(

Comment: Should not "status" be the "post_status"? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: That should work despite the `status` issue mentioned by @M-R (and which should be corrected). Do you have any filters that are altering `posts_per_page`?

Comment: I update the status filter and no working.
the posts_per_page is -1 (all)
but I find something: if I getting only 1 post when I use: xxx.com/country/netherlands on any other country but when I use xxx.com/Language/french or other language - IT'S WORK.
what do you think about?